# MYSQL - Zipcode radius - Optimize and return distance to outer select

Tags: mysql

I have a question about zipcode radius. The select below has a radius function I found. It is ok but a bit slow. Also, is there a way to return the distance to the outer select? I have hardcoded the LONGITUDE and LATITUDE for ease of this question.

Thanks in advance.
Phil

```
                       SELECT 
                            A.MEMBER_ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                       FROM MEMBER A,                                                                                         
                            DETAILS B,                                                                                             
                            ZIPCODE D
                      WHERE A.ZIPCODE_CODE IN (Select resultzip.ZIPCODE from                                                        
                                (SELECT                                                                                                        
                                    pos.ZIPCODE,                                                                                                 
                                    3958 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(( 39.946438 - abs(pos.LATITUDE)) * pi() / 180 / 2),2) +           
                                    COS( 39.946438 * pi()/180) * COS(abs(pos.LATITUDE) * pi() / 180) * POWER(SIN(( -74.915955 - pos.LONGITUDE) *
                                    pi() / 180 / 2), 2) )) AS distance_return_this_to_outer_select                                                                           
                                FROM ZIPCODE pos                                                                                           
                                HAVING distance_return_this_to_outer_select < 100                                                                        
                                ORDER BY distance_return_this_to_outer_select)                                                                                             
                                AS resultzip)                                                                                                                                                                             
                            AND A.ZIPCODE_CODE = D.ZIPCODE                                                                  
                            AND A.MEMBER_ID = B.MEMBER_ID                                
                            Limit 0,15;
```

Comment: One idea would be to find or construct a proper UDF, but if compiling code ain't your thing (it's definitely not mine) then you could construct a sproc instead. It won't be much faster, but it will be much more elegant. Then take a look at the EXPLAIN for that query to see which indexes would be most effective

Comment: Also, I suspect that asking MySQL to multiply constants by 2 or divide them by 180 is marginally less efficient than just telling it what those values are

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will look into a UDF

Comment: I found this - https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/ . Is it worth it to upgrade to mysql 5.6

Comment: Judging by the conclusions, no. You're still better off using the haversine formula, whether provided as a sproc or UDF.

Comment: In addition, I suspect that your query is slow for other reasons, but without seeing proper CREATE and INSERT statements (they don't need to be real, just representative), as well as the results of EXPLAIN on your existing query, it's going to be hard to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote a distance function, part of a bigger UDF runs in 150ns on AMD A10-6800K 2GHz processor. You can create a UDF wrapper around it (look at sql/udf_example.c in the MySQL source, search for myfunc_double) :

```
    #define R_EARTH_MILES 3963.1676
static inline double deg2rad(double deg) {
  return (deg * M_PI / 180);
}

static inline double rad2deg(double rad) {
  return (rad * 180 / M_PI);
}


    static inline double earth_distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
    {
        double dlat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1), dlon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
        double central_hs =  (1.0 - cos(dlat))/2.0 + cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * (1.0 - cos(dlon))/2.0;
        double central_angle = 2 * atan2(sqrt(central_hs), sqrt(1 - central_hs));
        return R_EARTH_MILES * central_angle;
    }
```

It uses the haversine method which relies on some clever trig identities to reduce the floating point operations.

Update:

Wrapped it into a standalone UDF that you should be able to deploy following the instructions in the README.md file:

http://github.com/spachev/mysql_udf_bundle

On second thought your slowness problems are likely not computation-performance related but rather from examining too many rows to answer the question because we cannot use a key to filter.

I would recommend storing your coordinates in a GEOMETRY type with a SPATIAL key, then using CONTAINS() function with a square with the center at your target point and search diameter as the side to filter out most of the points, and then filtering out the rest using earth distance method.

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/misc/article.php/c12615/MySQL-UDFs.htm  I have not created a UDF and my C experience is a bit rusty as well. What is the quickest way to get this done?

Comment: I coded it up for you (and whoever else might find it useful): https://github.com/spachev/mysql_udf_bundle

Comment: Thanks Sasha. I will look at it today.